# How to make a sprite jump in Pyglet?

Tags: python, pyglet

I've been making a personal project to remake a modified version of SUper Mario Bros.
So far, I've been able to add in the Mario sprite along with the ground and bricks. Now, I'm stuck with how to make Mario jump. Does anyone know how to do it?

EDIT: I already made a class for Mario, but can't get the jump to work. Any ideas why?

```
class mario(pyglet.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, batch):
        self._img_main = pyglet.image.load("Mario_Right.png")

        self.img_right1 = pyglet.image.load("Mario_Walk_Right1.png")
        self.img_right2 = pyglet.image.load("Mario_Walk_Right2.png")
        self.anim_right = pyglet.image.Animation.from_image_sequence([self.img_right1, self.img_right2], 0.5, True)
        pyglet.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self._img_main)
        self.time = 0

    def forward_movement(self, flag=True):
        if flag:
            self.image = self.anim_right 
        else:
            self.image = self._img_main
   def jump(self,flag=True):
        print time.time()-self.time
        self.y -= -10 +20**(time.time()-self.time+.2)

    def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
        self.keys_held.append(symbol)
        if symbol == pyglet.window.key.RIGHT:
            self.player.forward_movement(True)
        if symbol == pyglet.window.key.LEFT:
            self.player.time=time.time()
            self.player.jump()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create gravity on your code. First, create a class for your Mario. Set up their positions and speed. Put up method jump on your Mario.

```
#put this in your init
self.time = 0

#put this in your condition
if keymap[pyglet.window.key.RIGHT]:
    self.mario.time = time.time()
    self.mario.jump()

def jump(self):
    print time.time()-self.time
    self.y -= -10 +20**(time.time()-self.time+.2)
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it without using classes?

Comment: @afterend31 i dont think so. You have to create a class for the Mario because it is an object. You can't have a game without learning how to use them, so please, learn your classes first.

Comment: well I've managed to make a class already for it. But what you suggested didn't work. It shows an error message reading "Global name 'time' not found."

Comment: @afterend31 import the time module. Also, the keypress condition must be put on your update function, not on your Mario class.

Comment: i've managed to make it work but all it does is make Mario go up and up and up. how do I make him go down?

Comment: @afterend31 can you please edit your post to the newest code? Are you sure you've put what i've suggested properly?